# Prevent exiting html page

Tags: html

I want to use a html page to show all the products we sell in our store.
This page I want to show on a tablet so that customers can view it.
But I don't want the customers to be able to exit the website and use the tablet for something else.

The code itself isn't ready yet for publication but I was planing on using something like this:
http://www.thomasleflere.be/presentatie_in_reveal/presentatie.html

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean how can you write a really annoying web site that people will hate?    Can't help you.

Comment: What have you coded already?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that the you will own the tablet and want to restrict it to displaying your catalogue? (Perfectly reasonable). If so you might want to reword your question as it could be interpreted to mean you want to prevent random web surfers from exiting your site (annoying) and that won't be a popular question round here!

Answer (score 1):

If it is an iPad you might be able to use Kiosk mode.
http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App

I am not sure how to do this on other tablets but there could be a similar method.